# (impala) AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list

Tags: select, subquery, impala

I have a query like this, and appearantly Impala doesn't support subqueries in SELECT statement. How can I neatly rewrite it in Impala?

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT 1
          FROM
            table1 x,
            table2 y
          WHERE
            x.id = y.id
          LIMIT 1) = 1
    THEN
      'A'
    ELSE
      'B'
  END
    coln

FROM
...
```

Your query has the following error(s):

AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... 'A' coln
  FROM ...
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 x, table2 y WHERE x.id = y.id LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, ... 'B' coln
  FROM ...
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 x, table2 y WHERE x.id = y.id LIMIT 1)
```

No guarantees, haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Though, mine is actually a very large query, has multiple subqueries and it's intimidating to rephrase like this :) And it costs lots of  extra processor time if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I haven't checked the query plan myself, but the subquery in your example is independent from the main query, thus I guess it will be evaluated only once. If you have a dependent subquery, you may use a join instead, but the best way to do that depends on the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a cleaner solution is placing the subqueries into the FROM clause, thereby linking the subqueries to the main table through inner or left joins. I usually do this when dealing with complex types in Impala.

However, in your specific example you are trying to do a left join, defining a field for each row which indicates whether the join was successful ('A') or not ('B'). In this case you could do the following:

```
SELECT
  x.id, x.col2, x.col3, ...
  CASE
    WHEN y.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
    END
  coln
FROM table1 x LEFT JOIN
     table2 y USING (id)         
...
```